# Http.get returns array of objects, how to handle them in angular?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, I am trying to consume below api
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums

**album.ts**

```
export interface Album {
    userId: number;
    id: string;
    title: string;
}
```

**book.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookservService } from '../common/bookserv.service';
import { Album } from './album';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.scss']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  albums:Album;

  constructor(private serv:BookservService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serv.getAll()
     .subscribe(
       (value)=>{ 
         console.log(value);         
         this.albums=value;        
        },
       (error)=> console.log(error))
  }

}
```

**bookserv.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "./dataserv";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookservService extends DataService {

  constructor(http:HttpClient) {
    super("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",http)
   }
}
```

**dataserv.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { Album } from '../book/album';


export class DataService {

  constructor(private url: string,private http:HttpClient) {}
    
  getAll():Observable<Album> {
        return this.http.get<Album>(this.url)
        .pipe(catchError(
            (err: any, caught: Observable<Album>) => {
                console.log(err);
                return caught;
            }));
  }
 
}
```

**console.log**

```
(100) [{…},  {…}]
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "quidem molestiae enim"}
1: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa"}
2: {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "omnis laborum odio"}  etc..
```

`albums` is declared as object, but how array of objects directly assigned to object through below line
without error

```
this.albums=value;
```

At that same time if I declare album as array `albums:Album[]=[];` it throws error!!!

could anyone help me to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dataserv.ts`, update the return signature to return an array of `Album`

```js
export class DataService {
    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}
  
    public getAll(url: string): Observable<Album[]> {
      return this.http.get<Album[]>(url).pipe(
        catchError((err, caught) => {
          console.log(err);
          return caught;
        })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

In your `book.component.ts`, initialize albums to an empty array.

```js
public albums:Album[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your data.service.ts you can transforum your responsedata in your getAll http request like this

```
export class DataService {
  constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}

  // http calls
  getAll(url: string) {
    return this.http.get < albums: any > (url)
      .pipe(map((responseData) => {
        return {
          albums: responseData.albums.map(album => {
            return {
              userId: responsedata.album.userOd,
              id: responsedata.album.id,
              title: responsedata.album.title,
            };
          }),
        };
      }));
  }
}
```